# How can I add an external stylesheet to a UIWebView in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview

I have looked at various similar questions and answers and still cannot get this to work, so I'm adding my own question:

I'm playing with UIWebView. I can create a working html page with inline CSS. I cannot figure out how to get the CSS to load if it is in a file in the app resources group.

My code is:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"webViewPage2" ofType:@"html"];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                              [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    webView.opaque = NO;
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [htmlString release];
```

And my html call is this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/greek123.css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color: transparent;">

<h2>Some Title</h2>


<p>We can put instructions here. Such as: 
"uh-oh You should not have pushed that button!"
</p>


</body>

</html>
```

I would appreciate any ideas or solutions. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure about this so i'll add this as a comment, but I dont' think "/greek123.css" is correct.  The leading / would indicate that this is an absolute path, when it should be relative.

Comment: Also, you don't need a file handle to get the contents of a file into an NSString.  This is a method on NSString similar to stringWithContentsOfFile:

Comment: Thanks Darren, the leading slash was an experiment, but didn't work. Thanks for the tip on using stringWithContentsofFile. That's nice to know.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

change the baseURL of the UIWebView to the url of your mainbundle.

```
NSURL *mainBundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:mainBundleURL];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
webView.loadHTMLString(contentString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

Comment: I have a follow on question.. Let me know if I should make it a separate topic... With the same CSS inline as in an external file, I get very different results. Why would that be?

Comment: sorry, I have almost no knowledge about html and css. so I can't really help with this.

Comment: This is the best and most succinct answer to the question. Just solved the problem for me.

Comment: This should be emphasized.  There have been a lot of ugly workarounds I have seen that this cleanly solves.

Answer (score 8):

I think i have figured it out. the htmlString is simply an NSString we can replace text in it. this code worked for me

```
NSString *info = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your html file name" ofType:@"html"] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];

info=[info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"styles.css" withString:@"stylesIPad.css"];
```

Comment: That looks great.. I will try it asap.. David (OP)

Answer (score 5):

I thought I should post the entire code block to access an external CSS file. Hopefully, it will be useful to others:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *mainBundleURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypagename" ofType:@"html"];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                              [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    webView.opaque = NO;
    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:mainBundleURL];

    [htmlString release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL *BundleURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name your style" ofType:@"css"]];
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:BundleURL];
```

Comment: or you can make comething like this:   
newhmlString=[oldhtmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">" 
                                                                   withString:@"<style type=\"text/css\"> \n  @import url(\"your name css.css\");\n "]; 
end after add my previous string :))