# UIWebView Custom CSS

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I'm looking to inject a custom CSS stylesheet into `UIWebView`. The following is how I load the URL into the webview.

```
//load url into webview
NSString *strURL = @"http://example.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

I have spent a good few hours searching for solutions to no avail, so please forgive me if I'm completely starting in the wrong place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053109/how-can-i-add-an-external-stylesheet-to-a-uiwebview-in-xcode