# How to import css file in UIWebView when I am using loadHTMLString() method in swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I have a common css file and some dynamic html text. What I am trying to do is load the css file from the disk and use dynamic html text to display in the UIWebView instead of putting the same css as text over and over again with the html text.

I am trying this way.

```
var sometext = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\"></head>" + "<body><p>some text goes here</p></body></html>"
let mainbundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
let bundleURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: mainbundle)
self.webview.loadHTMLString(sometext, baseURL: bundleURL)
```

Now the problem is css is not getting applied to the html. Is there any one out there who can help, I think I am stuck.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You have to look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053109/how-can-i-add-an-external-stylesheet-to-a-uiwebview-in-xcode may you get help

Comment: @AshishKakkad : I have updated my code based on what you said, still css is not getting applied. can you help, please ?

Comment: please guys I need help on this, I am stuck.

Comment: Update for Swift - `self.webView.loadHTMLString(sometext, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)`

Comment: @russell Your question worked as answer for me. thanx

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My code was almost exactly the same as what Russell posted.

Adding my css file to the project was not enough. I had to reference the file in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list in the Build Phase settings.

How to reference the file in XCode 7:

1. Select the Build Phase tab
2. Scroll down to the "Copy Bundle Resources" section and add your file. (note: if *.css files don't appear in the list. Click the "Add Other" button)
3. In the options window choose "Create Folder Reference"

Thats it. This worked for me.

Comment: How would I know that css has been applied to my web view (bundle resource has several files) @Thu Trinh

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that when copying my file into my project I had to select "Create Folder Reference" instead of "Create Group" in the popup window.