# Which base url should I give a WebView in order for WebView to correctly load css and font files?

Tags: webview, react-native

In my Native React project I want to use a WebView. The HTML refers to an external css file and the css file refers to some custom fonts.

Given this hierarki:

```
app/
app/index.ios.js
app/android.ios.js
app/package.json
app/node_modules
app/android/
app/ios/
```

where should I put the files "mycss.css" and the "fonts/" folder and
what whould I use for the baseUrl ? Do the package manager automatically include css and font files, when building the ios and android builds?

```
    <WebView style={{flex: 1}}
             source={ { html:    my_html, 
                        baseUrl: ???} } />
```

Examining the code behind WebView on iOS shows that `baseUrl` is handed to a `UIWebView`. This StackOverFlow question [How can I add an external stylesheet to a UIWebView in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053109/how-can-i-add-an-external-stylesheet-to-a-uiwebview-in-xcode) shows how to set the baseUrl from Objective C, but what is the equivalent in Native React?

```
NSURL *mainBundleURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:mainBundleURL];
```

FWIW I am developing on iOS (but hopefully there is a way to make this work on both platforms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked.

Added a folder `web` and used this structure:

```
app/web/mycss.css
app/web/fonts
```

Used `web/` as base url.

The final piece of the puzzle is to add the `web` folder to the XCode project (do this in XCode). Otherwise the files in the `web` folder are not included in the bundle built for the ios device.

Comment: I managed to get this working on iOS...anybody know how to do it for Android?

Comment: @soegaard Can you show the content of "my_html" string ? 
I need to check how path are defined on image.